# asp.net Async call using BeginExecuteNonQuery db not firing

Tags: asp.net

my code fires off ExecuteNonQueryAsyc. In debug I see it hit command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(AsyncCommandCompletionCallback), command);
line but the sp is not really being fired off that gets called.  what am I doing wrong?

```
public static void ExecuteNonQueryAsyc(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Config.GetDbConnection() + ";Async=true;"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = procedureName;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (parameters != null)
            for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Count; index++)
                command.Parameters.Add(parameters[index]);

            connection.Open();
            command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(new AsyncCallback(AsyncCommandCompletionCallback), command);

    }
}

static void AsyncCommandCompletionCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    try
    {
        // Get our command object from AsyncState, then call EndExecuteNonQuery.
        cmd = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;
        cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: is the "new AsyncCallback(AsycCommandCompletionCallback)" needed? Shouldn't just the function name of the callback work, "AsycCommandCompletionCallback"? Not the cause of your problem, but why not also use "using" in callback?

Comment: not sure. I got the solution from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/76e542b4-e675-44bd-ad75-69c14769fec0/

Comment: also, have you tried putting a breakpoint at the cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery line to see if it is ever reached?

Comment: SO I didn't follow his example close enough.  He said You have the SqlConnection in a using scope.   When the using scope ends, the connection is closed.  So in your case the connection is closed before it completes (potentially).   I would change the ExecuteNonQueryAsyc to get rid of using block and add a try catch block and IF exception is raised, then close the connection and re-raise exception, otherwise let AsyncCommandCompletionCallback close the connection.

public static void ExecuteNonQueryAsyc(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters)

Comment: if you think it is closing the connection too soon, you could try throwing in a Thread.Sleep(10000) to give it plenty of time to complete. Then check to see if the SP ran as expected.

Comment: here is an example that checks to see if the IAsyncResult is completed before exiting the using block. Probably your best option. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se.aspx

Comment: thanks zach. i just got rid of the using and it worked.  but of course the whole solution was to try to keep the connection alive without setting a high timeout value. I just ended up doing a timeout=600 (10 minutes) and it all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had this same problem, so even though the answer is in the comments:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Config.GetDbConnection() + ";Async=true;"))
```

causes the connection to close before the command is completed (possibly before it even really gets called as it's on another thread which probably takes a few ticks to fire up and get started).